# Can't Solve Monoalphabetic Cryptosystem

Tags: abstract-algebra, cryptography, coding-theory

I've stumbled across the following Monoalphabetic Cryptosystem question in Thomas Judson's book on Abstract Algebra (http://abstract.ups.edu/aata/exercises-crypt.html).

> 3. Assuming that monoalphabetic code was used to encode the following secret message, what was the original message?
>
> ```
> APHUO EGEHP PEXOV FKEUH CKVUE CHKVE APHUO
> EGEHU EXOVL EXDKT VGEFT EHFKE UHCKF TZEXO
> VEZDT TVKUE XOVKV ENOHK ZFTEH TEHKQ LEROF
> PVEHP PEXOV ERYKP GERYT GVKEG XDRTE RGAGA
> ```
>
> What is the significance of this message in the history of cryptography?

Could somebody please attempt this question and confirm whether it is possible with the given encrypted message. The examples in the text promote the use of frequency analysis which suggests E=X (spaces and punctuation), the hint given in the solutions state V=E, E=X and K=R which don't have the same key (http://abstract.ups.edu/aata/solutions-1.html). I've gone through all 26 possible keys and the encoded message hasn't made any sense. Any help would be great.

Comment: What does "don't have the same key" and "26 possible keys" mean? Are you trying Caesar ciphers only, where the alphabet is simply "translated"/shifted? That is one type of monoalphabetic substitution, but it is not the only one. **Any** "shuffling" of the alphabet gives rise to a monoalphabetic substitution. All you need is to replace each letter in the cleartext by the same letter in the ciphertext throughout the message to get a monoalphabetic substitution.

Comment: There are 26! possible keys, way more than 26.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ArturoMagidin. Sorry I'll try and be more specific. I'm using a Caesar shift code with an encrypting function of '$f(p) = p + b \ mod (26)$' and a decrypting function of '$f^{-1}(p) = p - b \ mod (26)$'. E.g. $f(p)=p+3 \ mod(26)$ gives $A\mapsto D, B\mapsto E, ..., Z\mapsto C$. The hint suggests $V \mapsto E, E \mapsto X, K \mapsto R$ which would not use the same decrypting function.

Comment: There are only $26$ possible encryption possibilities, since in the formula $f(p) = p + b$, you know that $b$ must be some element in $\{0,1,2,\cdots,25\}.$  Therefore, all you have to do is write a decryption program that runs the decryption $(26)$ times, once for each possible value of $(b)$.  Then, have the computer program output each decryption.  You should be able to tell, in less than $(5)$ minutes, by glancing at the output, the sole decryption-attempt that is not gibberish.

Comment: @user2661923 I feel I have done exactly that and didn't get anything that made sense. I also have the issue of the hint providing multiple values for $b$ for its hint of $V \mapsto E, E \mapsto X, K \mapsto R$.

Comment: Then, there are three possibilities: [1] Either the problem composer made a bad error in the original encryption. [2] Your computer program has a bug in it. [3] The problem composer used some other means of encryption and erroneously indicated that the $f(p) = p + b$ method was used.

Comment: @user2661923 Ahh I feel as though [1] or [3] may have happened too, just wanted to make sure I wasn't making a stupid mistake - thankyou.

Comment: Assuming that your computer program is buggy, that you fix it, and successfully decrypt the message, there is a separate issue.  What strategy did the problem composer intend that you use to decrypt the message?  My strategy constitutes *brute force*, which has no real educational value.  The *analysis of frequency of letter combinations* approach makes more sense.  ...see next comment

Comment: If that was intended, you can use the brute force decryption to guide your thinking about how you could reach the same result via the intended path.

Comment: It's *not* a Caesar shift; I tried all 26 possibilities, and all of them produce gibberish.

Comment: Nowhere in the text does the author say this is a Caesar shift.  He clearly states that it is a monoalphabetic (simple substitution) cipher.  He also states that "Simple shift codes are examples of monoalphabetic cryptosystems" but just as in "dogs are examples of mammals" it doesn't mean that a monoalphabetic cipher must be a shift.

Comment: Given the level of treatment in the text, you may want to try the map $ap+b~pmod 26$. also there are lots of repeated k-grams in the ciphertext and you might want to try common words and subwords in english for those.  APHUO is an example. Also EGEH. Some cut accross the 5 letter groups but that's fine. For example FKEUHCK

Comment: For more hints, a plain "t" is a cipher "x".

Comment: @Randall Ahh okay I assumed it would be a Caesar shift given that he provided an example of one when discussing monoalphabetic ciphers. I hadn't considered that he expected the use of just frequency analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the convention that capital letters are ciphertext and small letters are plaintext.

Making the replacements E→x (space), K → r, and V → e, as specified in the hints, gives:

> APHUO G HPP XOeFr UHCreU CHre APHUO G HU XOeL XDrTeG FT HFr UHCrFTZ XOe ZDTTerU XOere NOHrZFT HT HrQL ROFPe HPP XOe RYrPG RYTGer GXDRT RGAGA

Note that XO appears in the onset of multiple words, including two examples of `XOe`.  The most common English word ending in `e` is `the`.  So assume X → t and O → h.

> APHUh G HPP theFr UHCreU CHre APHUh G HU theL tDrTeG FT HFr UHCrFTZ the ZDTTerU there NhHrZFT HT HrQL RhFPe HPP the RYrPG RYTGer GtDRT RGAGA

`theFr` could be `their`, so try F → i.

> APHUh G HPP their UHCreU CHre APHUh G HU theL tDrTeG iT Hir UHCriTZ the ZDTTerU there NhHrZiT HT HrQL RhiPe HPP the RYrPG RYTGer GtDRT RGAGA

And `Hir` = `air`?  Seems more likely than `fir`.  So, H → a.

> APaUh G aPP their UaCreU Care APaUh G aU theL tDrTeG iT air UaCriTZ the ZDTTerU there NharZiT aT arQL RhiPe aPP the RYrPG RYTGer GtDRT RGAGA

The letter U can occur before "h", or at the end of the word, including a two-letter word "aU".  Maybe U → s?

> APash G aPP their saCres Care APash G as theL tDrTeG iT air saCriTZ the ZDTTers there NharZiT aT arQL RhiPe aPP the RYrPG RYTGer GtDRT RGAGA

`aPP` is a multiply-occurring word with a double letter.  Maybe `all`?  So P → l.

> Alash G all their saCres Care Alash G as theL tDrTeG iT air saCriTZ the ZDTTers there NharZiT aT arQL Rhile all the RYrlG RYTGer GtDRT RGAGA

`T` occurs in two-letter words `iT` and `aT`.  So it could be `n` or `s`, but I've already used `s`.  So T → n.

> Alash G all their saCres Care Alash G as theL tDrneG in air saCrinZ the ZDnners there NharZin an arQL Rhile all the RYrlG RYnGer GtDRn RGAGA

`tDrneG` could be `turned`, so try D → u and G → d.

> Alash d all their saCres Care Alash d as theL turned in air saCrinZ the Zunners there NharZin an arQL Rhile all the RYrld RYnder dtuRn RdAdA

`Rhile`, `RYrld`, and `RYnder` could be `while`, `world`, and `wonder`, so R → w and Y → o.

> Alash d all their saCres Care Alash d as theL turned in air saCrinZ the Zunners there NharZin an arQL while all the world wonder dtuwn wdAdA

`Z` appears in the suffix `inZ` and the word `Zunners`, so try Z → g.

> Alash d all their saCres Care Alash d as theL turned in air saCring the gunners there Nhargin an arQL while all the world wonder dtuwn wdAdA

From here, I guess A → f, C → b, L → y, Q → m, and N → c.

> flash d all their sabres bare
> flash d as they turned in air
> sabring the gunners there
> chargin an army while all the world wonder dtuwn wdfdf

Which is a quote from "The Charge of the Light Brigade" by Alfred Tennyson.

> Flash'd all their sabres bare,
> Flash'd as they turned in air
> Sabring the gunners there,
> Chargin' an army, while all the world wonder'd.

But I can't figure out what the `tuwnwdfdf` at the end of the decoded text means.  Probably just a red herring.

The complete set of letter substitutions is:

- A → f
- C → b
- D → u
- E → x (space or apostrophe)
- F → i
- G → d
- H → a
- K → r
- L → y
- N → c
- O → h
- P → l
- Q → m
- R → w
- T → n
- V → e
- X → t
- Y → o
- Z → g

Comment: I reached the same conclusion using this nifty tool:  https://www.boxentriq.com/code-breaking/cryptogram

Comment: @Dan Thankyou for taking the time to produce the above. I was too fixated on it being a shift that I didn't consider using only frequency analysis. Your solution makes perfect sense!